# Drain for basement utility sink

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

I want to put a utility sink in my basement next to the washing machine.  The sewer is about 4 ft off the floor so it will need a pump.  There is an existing drain for the washing machine that connects with another drain for kitchen from floor above and then into the main stack.

Where in this setup is the best place to connect new drain from utility sink pump?  Split at the top where the washing machine attaches?

[image: Existing drain]

Comment: Will the sink be between the washing machine and the plumbing we see there, or will it be somewhere to the right of the washer?

Comment: Between, I plan on sliding the washer over to the right a bit